# Selenium/ Python How to get full text after expanding the text using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape reviews from TripAdvisor which, for long reviews, display only partial reviews that require clicking 'More' for the full review to be displayed. I tried getting the text after clicking more (and I can see that the text *is* expanded) but all I get is the partial review.

My code (to scrape one specific review) is as follow:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
review = driver.find_element_by_id("review_541350982") 
review.find_element_by_class_name("taLnk.ulBlueLinks").click()
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
new_review = driver.find_element_by_id("review_541350982")
entry = new_review.find_element_by_class_name("partial_entry")
print entry.text
```

This is the HTML before clicking on 'More':

```
<p class="partial_entry">This place blah blah blah What an...
<span class="taLnk ulBlueLinks" onclick="widgetEvCall('handlers.clickExpand',event,this);">More</span>
</p>
```

and this is the HTML after:

```
<p class="partial_entry">This place blah blah blah What an incredible monument from both a historic and construction point of view.</p>
<span class="taLnk ulBlueLinks" onclick="widgetEvCall('handlers.clickCollapse',event,this);">Show less</span>
```

I noticed that now `<span>` comes after `<p>` after clicking 'More'. Not sure if this is useful.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Noticed that introducing time.sleep(1) instead of driver.wait solved the problem. Wonder if there is a better way to do this such that the new entry is obtained automatically after it changes and not having to set an arbitrary waiting time?

Comment: Does the Xpath change after clicking "more"?

Comment: The Xpath for the text does not. But for the 'More' button (that becomes 'Show less' after clicking) yes, from ../div/p/span to ../div/span

Comment: And using the xpath after the click doesn't work?

Comment: It still returns the partial review.

Comment: I noticed including time.sleep(1) solved the problem! Is there a better way to do it though?

Comment: WebDriverWait would've been best. But something I also noticed is you instantiate WebDriverWait without `expected_conditions` and `By`. That would've told Selenium to wait for the element to be clickable, non-stale, etc

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much evident from your code that the **`WebDriverWait`** though defined but was not used properly. To print the full text **`This place blah blah blah What an incredible monument from both a historic and construction point of view.`**, you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#code block
review = driver.find_element_by_id("review_541350982") 
review.find_element_by_class_name("taLnk.ulBlueLinks").click()
new_review = driver.find_element_by_id("review_541350982")
full_review = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(new_review.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='partial_entry']"),'This place blah blah blah What an incredible monument from both a historic and construction point of view.'))
entry = new_review.find_element_by_class_name("partial_entry")
print entry.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the review and click more:

```
review = driver.find_element_by_id("review_541350982")
partial_text = review.find_element_by_tag_name('p')
partial_text.find_element_by_tag_name('span').click()
```

Relocate the review using XPath and output the text:

```
new_review = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@id="review_541350982"]//p)[1]')
print(new_review.text)
```

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately, this still returns the partial review.

Comment: Not sure why yours won't work. Maybe because I'm using the chrome driver. Still though, glad you could get yours to work